# How to create flex box in vuetify in right corner?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

My problem is how to create a flex box or just a box in vuetify in right bottom corner as you can see in the picture? Thank you!

```
    <template>
<v-card
    class="d-flex justify-end pa-2"
    outlined
    tile
  >
    <div>I'm an inline flexbox container!</div>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gikbB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<template>
<v-card
    outlined
    tile
  >
   <v-card-actions class="justify-end">
    <div>I'm an inline flexbox container!</div>
   </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>
```